# How to get store and assign it to spied variable

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have two files: x.component and x.service

x.service.ts

```
store$: Store<DogsStore>;

constructor(private store: Store<DogsStore>) {
  this.store$ = store;
}
```

x.component.ts

```
constructor(private xService: X) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.xService.store$.select('something').subscribe(...)
}
```

Testing `x.component` I'm getting an error that `cannot subscribe of undefined`. In `x.spec.ts` I'm using x.service.spy.ts where I have

```
store$: Store<DogsStore>;
```

as you can see I didn't initialize it because I can't use something like `store$: Store<DogsStore> = new Store()`. How can I get the store and assign it to variable? Maybe there is other issue to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I got the question right, here is how to do it:

Basically, your app module provides the store, yet your test doesn't. So in your spec file, part of the `beforeEach` should provide it by importing it:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SomeModule,
        StoreModule.provideStore(reducer), // or your reducer name
        ....
      ],
      ....
    });
```

and then spy on it (still in the `beforeEach` call):

```
    spyOn(getTestBed().get(Store), 'dispatch').and.callThrough();
```

This way your component will get it.

Now to get access to the dispatch wrapper you should inject it in the test:

```
it('test something', inject([Type1, Type2, Store],
    (dep1: Type1, dep2: Type2, store) => {
       expect(store.dispatch.calls.count()).toEqual(<count_value>);
    }
```

Now note that in the method signature I left store untyped, this is because otherwise the static checker complains that `store.dispatch` has no member `calls`